# Azure Synapse Serverless. HashBytes: The query references an object that is not supported in distributed processing mode

Tags: azure-synapse

I am receiving the error "The query references an object that is not supported in distributed processing mode" when using the HASHBYTES() function to hash rows in Synapse Serverless SQL Pool.

The end goal is to parse the json and store it as parquet along with a hash of the json document.  The hash will be used in future imports of new snapshots to identify differentials.

Here is a sample query that produces the error:

```sql
SELECT HASHBYTES('sha2_256', csvdata.rec)
FROM OPENROWSET(
        BULK 'json/*/*/*/*/*.json.gz',
        DATA_SOURCE = 'landingzone',
        FORMAT = 'csv',
        fieldterminator ='0x0b',
        fieldquote = '0x0b'
) with (rec nvarchar(max)) as csvdata;
```

This example also produces the error:

```sql
SELECT HASHBYTES('sha2_256', '{"mydoc": {"key":"value"}}')
FROM OPENROWSET(
        BULK 'json/*/*/*/*/*.json.gz',
        DATA_SOURCE = 'landingzone',
        FORMAT = 'csv',
        fieldterminator ='0x0b',
        fieldquote = '0x0b'
) with (rec nvarchar(max)) as csvdata;
```

This example produces a hash as expected:

```sql
SELECT HASHBYTES('sha2_256', '{"mydoc": {"key":"value"}}');
```

I also receive the error if I first create an external table and use the hashbytes() function when querying from the external table.

Thank you in advance for your advice.

Comment: Jason, I've been able to reproduce the error in other circumstances than using hashbytes(). I'm digging into this further, and I'll update you on progress later today.

Comment: You have `BULK 'json/*/*/*/*/*.json.gz'` and then `FORMAT = 'csv',`. Is that correct? Also can you post an example of the value of `rec` column? What's the type? I did see Ron's answer btw, but just curious.

Comment: @Kashyap, here's the syntax docs i'm following https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql/query-json-files . It works if i just select columns and omit the call to hashbytes.  The json document is `{"mydoc": {"key":"value"}}`.  Its the same as above - i just created a file with a few hundred rows of this for testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jason, I'm sorry, hashbytes() is not supported against external tables.

Comment: bummer - thank you for looking into this for me.

Comment: What are some other not supported functions? any documentation i can use?

Answer (score 2):

I would like to announce that Hashbytes function is now supported in distributed queries (when used with external tables or openrowset) in serverless SQL pools in Azure Synapse!

On this link you can see [Transact-SQL features supported in Azure Synapse SQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql/overview-features#query-language).

Answer (score 0):

The list of supported T-SQL commands in serverless environments is available [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql/overview-features#query-language). This article notably states that cryptographic functions (listed also [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cryptographic-functions-transact-sql)) such as HASHBYTES() are not (yet) supported.