# How to do random sampling of rows in Synapse Analytics serverless SQL pool?

Tags: sql, azure, t-sql, hash, azure-synapse

Is there any way in SQL to take a random sample of *N* rows (or *M*% if necessary) rows from a linked external data source, using the Azure Synapse Analytics serverless SQL pool?

[Cryptographic functions are not available in the serverless SQL pool](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67967393/850883), so basically I can't use `RAND()` or `CHECKSUM(NEWID())`, e.g. to define a condition to filter rows by comparing to my desired value of *N* (or *M*):

> FUNCTION 'RAND' is not supported.

I *can* use `HASHBYTES` against a field in my external data source, but my table doesn't contain a unique ID per row.

```
SELECT title, director, HASHBYTES('sha2_256', title)
FROM external_table
```

Ideally the sampling should be statistically sound, rather than relying on some implementation detail of the database (like `TABLESAMPLE` would, which anyway is also not available in the serverless pool).

Comment: Interesting question given the lack of ‘traditional’ SQL Server methods.  I would use a Synapse Notebook for this, it’s a good use-case for it because the functionality isn’t there.  Sorry I’m away from keyboard at the moment as it’s Christmas but can knock up an example for you in a week or so if one doesn’t materialise.

Comment: This looks like an interesting read: https://sparkbyexamples.com/spark/spark-sampling-with-examples/?amp

Comment: How about `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY SomeColumn) % 11 = 1`

Comment: @GregGalloway Looks like that could work, though I believe it needs to include a subquery. If you post an answer showing a full SQL query I might accept it if a better one doesn't show up. Thx!

Comment: @wBob I'm specifically looking for a serverless SQL solution, so that I don't need to have my own cluster running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expanding on the comment from @GregGalloway

The query would look something like this:

```
WITH [cte_sample] as (SELECT 
    [title], 
    [director], 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [ProductKey]) % 20 as [Sample_Group]
FROM 
    [external_table])
SELECT
    [title], 
    [director]
FROM
    [cte_sample]
WHERE
    [Sample_Group] = 1
```

Used % 20 to give a 5% sample size.

Comment: One of my constraints is I don't have a unique ID key per row (this example uses [ProductKey]) but this solution is about as good as I'm going to get -- I can make it work!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure its the exact problem however I used the below to generate a random integer in serverless sql pools, thought it may be useful for somebody looking for a basic RAND() feature in serverless sql

```
DECLARE @INT VARCHAR(150) = (SELECT CAST(NEWID() AS NVARCHAR(150)))

SET @INT = REPLACE(@INT,'-','')

WHILE ISNUMERIC(@Int) = 0 
BEGIN
    
    SET @INT = REPLACE(@INT, SUBSTRING(@INT, PATINDEX('%[^0-9.-]%', @INT), 1), '')

END;


DECLARE @Id INT
SET @Id = CAST(LEFT(@INT,7) AS INT)
```