# Synapse Serverless SQL - tablesample alternative

Tags: azure-synapse

I am trying to sample data from a table/file in Synapse.

I was hoping to be able to use TABLESAMPLE but it does not seem to work with Serverless SQL Pools.

I am assuming it is a limitation of the BULK OPENROWSET function

Can someone either point out if I am doing something wrong or an alternative that avoids scanning the whole table (i.e. TOP(x))

Query example:

```
SELECT
    TOP 100 *
FROM
    OPENROWSET(
        BULK 'https://aad1ciocorpdataprod.dfs.core.windows.net/gold/Dim/OSC_Account/',
        FORMAT = 'DELTA'
    ) TABLESAMPLE (5 ROWS) AS [result]
```

Returns:

```
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'.
```

Comment: Have you considered using ROW_NUMBER to generate a sample group - that lets you sample the data?  see here for an example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73040743/8225807

Answer (score 0):

For the serverless SQL pool in Azure Synapse Analytics, you can create an external data source and an external file format to access and query data stored in external files like Parquet, CSV, JSON, etc.

The Delta format that you mentioned in your query is also a compression of SnappyCodec/snappy.parquet

For example, I have created table called student in databricks. Reading the CSV file and writing as PARQUET and then writing to storage account as DELTA format.

**The below image shows CSV to PARQUET:**
[image]

[image]

**The below images shows writing data to ADLS in DELTA format:**
[image]

**Delta Log folder created and Student table saved as snappy.parquet:**
[image]

As you can see the Delta format is also a snappy. Parquet format.

Using the same file I am querying my external table students.

```
SELECT  TOP  100 *
FROM  OPENROWSET(
BULK  'https://synapseadlsgen2july23.dfs.core.windows.net/folder1/new/part-00000-b755396a-78bf-4c68-8e57-89ffb8428218-c000.snappy.parquet',
FORMAT = 'PARQUET'
) AS Student
```

[image]

Also, in your code Additionally, specifying (5 ROWS) after the table alias is not necessary.